# Question about necessary experimental recruitment size given particular design

Tags: probability, statistical-power

Suppose each individual faces a series of test-rounds, each a part of a broader task. In each round, they face some probability that the task ends, and some probability they continue to the next round. Specifically, define $p^t$ as the probability the task as a whole concludes in some round $t$. If they continue to get the "continue" result, they end up facing $T$ total rounds (that is, they keep facing different draws in each round, however there is some maximum number $T$ such that, if you reach round $T$, that's the last round with certainty). Bringing this together, the probability some individual $i$ faces at least three rounds, then, is $(1-p^1)\times (1-p^2) \times (1-p^3)$. For now, we can assume that $p$ is constant across rounds, though this won't hold in the most general case.

What I'm specifically wondering is what is the best way to figure out the number of individuals we'll need to recruit (call this $N$) to ensure, with probability $r$, that we end up observing $Z$ individuals make it through at least $t<T$ rounds. Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!!

If there's any more information that would be helpful, just let me know! Thank you!!

Comment: Could you explain why you think this question is about Chebyshev's Inequality? Although that can be useful when you know nothing about the shape of a distribution, in this question you know the distribution exactly!

Comment: @whuber That's a very fair question! I was leaning towards using it for two reasons: 1) The question simplifies the circumstances and context a fair amount, and while I think this particular element of the broader problem can be modeled like a binomial distribution, the problem as a whole isn't exactly describing a standard binomial distribution, so I was hoping to keep it a bit more general and standardized. 2) I'm mostly using this as a "worst case scenario" bound (so even if the assumption about the modeling equivalence isn't entirely bought by the reader, some of the other analysis can>

Comment: Please pose the question you *actually face.*  Otherwise--as seems to have occurred here--you wind up with a question that may have nothing to do with your problem.  The question as posed has such a simple answer--namely, just compute the cumulative Binomial probability you have asked for--that it likely trivializes the situation rather than illuminates it.

Comment: @whuber I just added the specifics of the problem- I can remove the original post's text, or delete this question and reask it if you think that's best! Thank you!

Comment: You have done the appropriate thing by editing the post.  You needn't feel obliged to keep the original text in there, unless you think it might help.  I would also suggest changing the title to better reflect the problem (rather than anticipating a particular solution, which I strongly suspect will not apply).

Comment: @whuber done and done, thank you for your insight!